# Replacing the mouse click in Morrowind

Tags: mods, the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind, accessibility

Are there any mod which can replace left/right click button for various action, I need this because I am a person suffered from a rsi injury of my right index finger and I hate clicking but yet I would like to play Morrowind happily. Thanks.

EDIT:
What benefit me most is a function to replace left click with a key on keyboard, for example, when you are talking to some guy and there is some dialog and choices you can do such as Barter, latest rumors, etc. Is there any possible to do it like when I move my cursor to the particular choice and press a key such as spacebar and the corresponding choice will be made. I just hate clicking.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your needs?  I'm not sure what you mean by "replace left/right click button for various action".  :-)

Comment: Can't you use Windows' tools like MouseKeys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might check and see if you can't just rebind the key in the options menu.  Many games support both keyboard and mouse input, and I seem to remember that you can rebind most actions from mouse buttons to keys, although selecting dialog options (and the like) might be always mapped to the mouse.

If the game *makes* you use the mouse, [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm) is my go-to solution for these problems.  It's free, and it downloads and installs quickly, and it works with games in many cases.

In this case, you might be able to get away with:

```
a::LButton
b::RButton
```

which would map your <kbd>a</kbd> key to send the left mouse button, and your <kbd>b</kbd> key to send the right mouse button.  You can replace 'a' and 'b' with whatever keys you want.  Some keyboard keys have special names in AHK; there's a list of all the keys [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm).

Open a Notepad window, and copy and paste this line into the blank Notepad document.  Save it as "mousebuttonremap.ahk" (**including the quotes**) and then you can double click to load it.  There will be a little "A" icon in your tray that you can right click to quit the script, when you need your keys back.

Sometimes this method doesn't work with games, in which case you may want to try:

```
a::
SendPlay {LButton}
return
b::
SendPlay {RButton}
return
```

If this still doesn't work, you may have to tweak the script a bit more to work with the specific game you're trying to play.  There's a [FAQ entry](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/FAQ.htm#games) about issues with games that might help in this case.

---

Update: According to [other users](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic43337.html) on the AHK forums, SendEvent works best, and you may need to edit Morrowind.ini to set "Background Keyboard=1" for this to work properly.

Comment: +1. While my answer suggested AutoHoyKey, your answer covered the setting process as well

Comment: I added a line "Numpad5::SendPlay {LButton}" and it works like a charm in windows, but failed in Morrowind. I should try the FAQ.

Comment: Turns out "Numpad5::Click" will do. Thanks!

Comment: @gunbuster363, you might check [this thread](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic43337.html) on the AHK forums.  They modified the Morrowind.ini file and used SendEvent.

Answer (score 4):

This is a general solution, not involving a mod for Morrowind.

You can try using MouseKeys, an accessibly tool for Windows. You can turn it on through `Control Panel -> Accessibility Options`, under the `Mouse` tab.

When turned on, the <kbd>5</kbd> button on your numpad acts as the left mouse button.

Another alternative is using a 3rd party tool called [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), which allows you to re-map keyboard and map keys on your keyboard.

Comment: It somehow doesn't work in Morrowind, although it works in windows.

Comment: Added another alternative, try it and tell me if it helps